# Pip upgrading arcgis completely broke pip

Tags: python, pip, arcgis

Overview: While running Python 3.6, after upgrading my arcgis package, scripts no longer recognizes many packages and pip itself completely broke, making it impossible to upgrade or uninstall any packages.

Background Info: Fairly recently, when I run a particular program of mine, I have been seeing a deprecation message connected to the arcgis package. So, I upgraded the arcgis package to see if it fixed it. It seemed to install correctly but then when trying to run my program, I'd get errors for other packages, like `folium` or `requests`. I then tried upgrading Python and initially, it worked. I used pip to install pandas and requests but right after I installed arcgis, everything broke again. So then when trying to uninstall arcgis (or do anything else pip related) I get this error:

FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'C:\Users\*myuserpath*\AppData\Local\.certifi'

I've uninstalled Python but it doesn't change anything. pip install *any package* results in this error. I tried reverting back to Python 3.6 but the installer wasn't available from the python site, only 3.9.

What could have been changed or affected by this arcgis installation?

Comment: As far as I remember, `pip` internally depends on `urllib3`. Upgrade of `requests` could result in inconsistent or broken version of it. Try using `get-pip.py` from [this page](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/) to restore pip

Comment: If I run that get-pip.py file, I get the same error - that the file already exists. I can't figure out what it's trying to copy or create.

Comment: AFAIK ArcGis comes with its own Python installation. That is normally separate from any other installation you have, meaning you have to install 3rd party modules more than once. It sounds as though in your case ArcGis is installing its own copy of Python over your vanilla Python installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be two primary issues you're dealing with. The first is as @BoarGules mentioned, that arcgis does a 'full' install with all its dependencies and that could be causing problems. Secondly, the newest requests library seems to have some issues as well, at least from what I've experienced. So let's get started fixing all this.

There's probably a few different ways to fix this, so this is just one of the many. First, uninstall python and delete the python folder from your AppData folder - in your case, it would be the Python 3.9 folder. Re-install Python and check your site-packages folder making sure it only contains the default Python packages. Open up a command prompt and do a pip install of something basic, like pandas. If that goes well, then the first hurdle is over.

When it comes time to install arcgis again, you'll want to use this instead

```
pip install arcgis --no-deps
```

this will prevent the doubling up of any of the packages or whatever seems to be happening. You will need to then also install these:

```
pip install ujson
pip install requests_ntlm
```

Next, when you come to installing requests, use an older library, like this one:
pip install requests==2.20.0

That should get things back up and running.