# Arc gis import fileerror python

Tags: python, arcgis

I'm getting the following error when trying to import the arcgis module

```
C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/me/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import arcgis.gis as arcgis
  File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\arcgis\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import features, geoanalytics, geocoding, geometry
  File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\arcgis\features\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .feature import Feature, FeatureSet, FeatureCollection
  File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\arcgis\features\feature.py", line 25, in <module>
    from arcgis.gis import Layer
  File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\arcgis\gis\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from arcgis.gis._impl._con._helpers import _is_http_url
  File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\arcgis\gis\_impl\_con\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ._connection import Connection
  File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\arcgis\gis\_impl\_con\_connection.py", line 26, in <module>
    certifi_win32.generate_pem()
  File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\certifi_win32\wincerts.py", line 113, in generate_pem
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(PEM_PATH))
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\os.py", line 225, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\.certifi'
```

Comment: This appears to be answered by https://stackoverflow.com/a/69427012/165305